# How to refresh image display white maintaining same text win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

Is there any code that i can call to refresh the image display(used paint) on the win32 but maintaining the messages?
I only wish to update only the fingerprint image and show the live image. The text windows + the other picture remains.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l1XV.jpg

**EDIT:**

```
case WM_PAINT:

    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

refresh=!refresh;
    if((start==true)&&(refresh==true)&&(stop!=true))
    {       
        if(cycle==0)
            {
                myKad(hWnd);
                    cycle=1;
            }
    windowName = MultiByteStringToWideString(name1, CP_ACP);
    LoadAndBlitBitmap(windowName.c_str(), hdc,500,0);
    fingerprint();
    LoadAndBlitBitmap(TEXT("outresized.bmp"), hdc,500,300);
    refresh=!refresh;
    char buffer[100]; // Just to show the # of loops it is at
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",round);
     windowName = MultiByteStringToWideString(buffer, CP_ACP);
    ::MessageBox(NULL,windowName.c_str(), __T("Error"), MB_OK);//just to show #loop.
    round++;

    ::MessageBox(NULL,__T("REFRESHED"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);

    //RedrawWindow(hWnd,&fingerprintSection,NULL,RDW_INTERNALPAINT|RDW_VALIDATE|RDW_UPDATENOW|RDW_NOCHILDREN);
    InvalidateRect( hWnd, &fingerprintSection, TRUE );
    }
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

---

**OLD**

this is the what i tried but still unsuccessful

```
RECT fingerprintSection;//area that i want to refresh
fingerprintSection.left=500;
fingerprintSection.top=300;
fingerprintSection.bottom=540;
fingerprintSection.right=660;

if (wmId!=IDM_STOP)
    {

    fingerprint(); //this function will save the fingerprint to "outresized.bmp"

    LoadAndBlitBitmap(TEXT("outresized.bmp"), hdc,500,300);
    InvalidateRect( hWnd, &fingerprintSection, TRUE );
}
```

this is my bitmap code if u want to see

```
bool LoadAndBlitBitmap(LPCWSTR szFileName, HDC hWinDC,int x,int y)
{
// Load the bitmap image file
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, szFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE);
// Verify that the image was loaded
if (hBitmap == NULL) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("LoadImage Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}

// Create a device context that is compatible with the window
HDC hLocalDC;
hLocalDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hWinDC);
// Verify that the device context was created
if (hLocalDC == NULL) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("CreateCompatibleDC Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}

// Get the bitmap's parameters and verify the get
BITMAP qBitmap;
int iReturn = GetObject(reinterpret_cast<HGDIOBJ>(hBitmap), sizeof(BITMAP),
    reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(&qBitmap));
if (!iReturn) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("GetObject Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}

// Select the loaded bitmap into the device context
HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hBitmap);
if (hOldBmp == NULL) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("SelectObject Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}

// Blit the dc which holds the bitmap onto the window's dc
BOOL qRetBlit = ::BitBlt(hWinDC, x, y, qBitmap.bmWidth, qBitmap.bmHeight,
    hLocalDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
if (!qRetBlit) {
    ::MessageBox(NULL, __T("Blit Failed"), __T("Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}

// Unitialize and deallocate resources
::SelectObject(hLocalDC, hOldBmp);
::DeleteDC(hLocalDC);
::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
return true;
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Give us some code, explain better what you want to achieve, and what is currently happening.

Comment: Create a control/window with the following properties.. `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _T("Static"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_BITMAP`  then set its image using: `SendMessage(Hwnd, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(hBitmap));`  The `SendMessage` can be done in `WM_PAINT` so that it redraws when it needs to.. Otherwise just `SendMessage` when you need to repaint the control manually.. It's what I did for a chat client and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your case, since there is no text or part of other image over the fingerprint.

You just need the [`RECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the fingerprint to pass as second parameter.

From what I see in your post, you seem to load and blit fingerprint in `LoadAndBlitBitmap`, so you could use that function to update some global `RECT` variable in order to pass it as a second parameter.

Without seeing more code all I can advise for now is this:

```
if (wmId!=IDM_STOP)
{
    fingerprint();

    LoadAndBlitBitmap(TEXT("outresized.bmp"), hdc,500,300);

    InvalidateRect( hWnd, &RectOfMyFingerprint, TRUE );
}
```

### EDIT:

You can use your button to capture and save the image of the bitmap.

Then all you need to do is invalidate the window to redraw captured image.

Try moving your `LoadAndBlitBitmap` into `WM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
         BeginPaint();

         LoadAndBlitBitmap();

         EndPaint;
    }
```

Your button handler should look like this:

```
if ( wmId == IDM_STARTSCANNING)
{
    fingerprint(); // capture your bitmap
}
else
    if (wmId == IDM_STOP)
    {
        // order redrawing
        InvalidateRect( hWnd, &RectOfMyFingerprint, TRUE ); 
    }
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still not refreshing. i updated my question. Please check. thanks

Comment: @user3396218: 
 
I have edited my answer. If it fails again, try replacing the second parameter of `InvalidateRect` with `NULL` so the entire window is redrawn. This will be useful to us since we can exclude the possibility of wrong coordinates being sent.

Comment: there's one more problem with this. The content changes but it doesn't really show on the window unless i pop up a messagebox everytime it refreshes. Also, if i moved the windows, it'll only show. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @user3396218: I really don't understand what are you trying to achieve here. What exactly "The content changes" means? At this point I do not see where you pop `MessageBox`, nor do I see the relevant code. At least update your question with this info, so I can try to help. I strongly advise you to upload a **minimal** demo program **that illustrates your problem**. Best regards.

Comment: hi i updated the post. and here's the full code if u want to see. thanks http://pastebin.com/nR5r32Hx

The fingerprint image changes but it doesn't show and update on the windows unless a messagebox is popped up. Thanks

Comment: @user3396218: OK, I will have a look tomorrow, since I was up whole night.

Comment: thanks man but it's fixed. It seems that i put my drawing function in the wrong place. It shouldn't be at WM_Paint because (wmId=WM_PAINT) only when the windows needs to be painted ( ie starting up, moving the windows causing it to send this WM) Hence, by putting the InvalidateRect function on another loop apart from WM_PAINT and it's fixed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3396218: OK, then all is settled? If you still need help just leave a comment. Best regards and good luck with your project!